# how does overriding a superclass method in a subclass cause the overridden method to be called by an object of type of super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

An example  is the assignment 3 from stanford's cs193p:

```
-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
int score = 0;

if ([otherCards count] == 1)
{
    playingCard *otherCard = [otherCards firstObject];
    if ([self.suit isEqualToString: otherCard.suit])
    {
        score = 1;
        NSLog(@"%d",score);
    }else if (self.rank == otherCard.rank)
    {
        score = 4;
    }
}

return score;
}
```

The above is the implementation of a method in a subclass of Cards called PlayingCard.

```
- (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
int score = 0;

for (Card *cards in otherCards)
    if ([cards.contents isEqualToString:self.contents])
        score = 1;

return  score;
}
```

The above is the implementation of match in Cards.

```
-(void)chooseCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];

if (!card.isMatched)
{
    if (card.isChosen)
    {
        card.chosen = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        for (Card *otherCard in self.cards)
        {
            if (otherCard.isChosen && !otherCard.isMatched)
            {
                int matchScore = [card match:@[otherCard]];
                if (matchScore)
                {
                    self.score += matchScore * MATCH_BONUS;
                    card.matched = YES;
                    otherCard.matched = YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    otherCard.chosen = NO;
                    self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        self.score -= COST_TO_CHOOSE;
        card.chosen = YES;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see above, the method match is called by an instance of Card and not playingCard, yet the results follow implementation from playingCard

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Without the context of the call, seeing the implementation of the super and subclass doesn't give any indication as to why you're getting unexpected results.  It's likely that you have a PlayingCard in that scope and not a Card, despite the intention.

Comment: @adamdc78 I've included the context of the call.

Comment: Add the following line inside the method: `NSLog(@"%@", card);` after obtaining the object.

Comment: It doesn't.  Objective-C is "duck typed".  An instance of a class responds to the methods that that class knows, either because they are defined in the class or in it's superclass.  Importantly, the type of the *pointer* has no effect whatsoever on what method is actually called.

Comment: (Do you understand the difference between an instance of a class and a pointer??)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a virtual base class ,in superClass cards

```
-(int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
{
  // do nothing
}
```

and you need two subclass such as PlayingCard ,NormalCard .YOU Should implementation the function in each subClass.